# Как сделать прозрачный фон формы в Visual Studio на C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Мне нужно сделать прозрачным только фон, ничего больше. Пробовал через опцию "Opacity" но тогда прозрачным стает все, и форма и кнопки и все остальное. Помогите пожалуйста, желательно представить кусочек кода, а то я в C# недавно.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Я пользуюсь WinForms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Для WinForms:**

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;  
this.AllowTransparency = true;  
this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;//цвет фона  
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;//он же будет заменен на прозрачный цвет
```

*То же самое можно сделать и из конструктора...*

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы границы остались и за них можно было потянуть/растянуть форму?

Answer (score 3):

**Для WPF**

Установите у окна (`Window`) свойства `AllowTransparency = true` и `Background=Transparent`.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать для WinForms?

Comment: Для WinForms не знаю, не пробовал.